# Error: The tag 'StackedColumnSeries' does not exist in XML namespace?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a chart controls in my WPF application in Visual Studio 2012 i can run this code with out an error but in Visual Studio 2012 i'm facing some issues like below error.

Error: The tag 'StackedColumnSeries' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit'.

Can any one help me please thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

I put it here for fellows like me:

> The WPF Toolkit hasn't released a new version since the April 2010
>   Silverlight Toolkit was released with stacked series support, so
>   what's in the current download is not the latest stuff. However, you
>   can get the latest version of the Data Visualization assembly
>   (binaries and code) for all supported platforms as part of my
>   **Development Release**: [download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx)

From here:http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9997400#comment-1378418769